# Save website to homescreen on iphone - force name

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

When you save a website to your iphone home screen, it pick's the site title as the name to save as, is it possible to force as a specific name regardless of which page they bookmark it on a domain?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I have you right, when you're in Safari and you press Add to Home Screen, you are given an opportunity to changed the name of the home screen icon. After you've edited the name, press Add and you're set.

Comment: Example scenario:
My page has a title of 'this is my homepage'
When I click 'add to home screen'
It then truncates to 'this is my..'
Anyone to prevent this? Or forcefully detect if it was iphone, set the page title as 'Home' for them to save to homescreen

Comment: You could detect the device with javascript. Something like if( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) { document.title = "New Title";}

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question so not sure why it's been accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 11):

On iOS 6 and later you can override the name by using this meta tag:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="App Title" />
```

Unfortunately though, it doesn't get around the problem (bug?) that you can easily fit more characters in most shortcut names than Safari naturally truncates to, but at least it means you can choose a shorter name for your app, and it doesn't require any JavaScript.